# Use a function in $this->set() with CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I'm just wondering how I can use/define my own function using the `$this->set()` method in CakePHP? I want to do something like this...

*AppController.php*

```
<?php
    function checkSetup() {
        if ($this->Auth->user('setup') == 'notcomplete') { return true; }
    }

    $this->set('isSetup', checkSetup());
?>
```

And then I will be able to access and call it in my view file:

```
<?php if ($isSetup): ?>
You haven't setup your profile yet!
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried that, but It clearly doesn't work as I get a massive fatal error. Any ideas/suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->set('isSetup', checkSetup());
```

That line needs to be inside some function in order to be called. Presumably you want it in the beforFilter of your app controller - something like this:

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('isSetup', checkSetup());
    }

    function checkSetup() {
        if ($this->Auth->user('setup') == 'notcomplete') { return true; }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't realize it had to be in a function. Cheers mate ;)